# Escaping ampersands in urls in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-2.0, ampersand

I'm building an ASP.NET 2.0 application that involves a lot of urls with several parameters.  For example:

```
http://www.myapp.com/default.aspx?param1=val&param2=val2
```

I know that a link to that page should look like this in the HTML, with the ampersands escaped:

```
<a href='http://www.myapp.com/default.aspx?param1=val&amp;param2=val2>Text</a>
```

So when I'm generating HTML manually for a `Literal` control, I need to escape my ampersands.  But do I need to do the same thing when assigning to the `NavigateUrl` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WEB.UI.WEBCONTROLS.HYPERLINK.NAVIGATEURL%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV2.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)) property of a `HyperLink`, or is that done for me automatically?  In general, where is this taken care of automatically in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All ASP.Net server-side controls encode user-supplied values in the HTML they generate, except where noted otherwise in the documentation.